# Error when getting C# generated public keys in PHP

Tags: c#, php, openssl, public-key

I created public key using the following code in C#:

```cs
using (var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
{
    rsa.PersistKeyInCsp = false;
    m_publicKey = rsa.ExportParameters(false);
}
```

And exported the public key to a file using the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406888/c-sharp-rsa-public-key-output-not-correct/28407693#28407693).

The output file looks like:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEA498EWxuZK/KsUgIEusEt
QOJulgTHwb8C4avtzJnzhosTeKooXvyGFPpex6HcQGSRqrWpNr2yhw1BvJvH2UyE
Jisl5BJA5Za+ofmbGifCFwCllZ37U1YpOmqpB2Yt+yYElGh5dp+lqs5Q3u3nPknd
nLS3bxH7qlZBvR9YPWj9x7IuSXJyopAmdJato8xeNHzmBxWD8FgQKICFpLtGsPXq
XRwT0imTs6/EcMqq6fdlp0OyBKyZjw6t47gMeqiuSYz6k41Nf/SbtIC4snUyoUgI
TvnHjWe1cY7js4kY62A9ZpHX0NpG7JXctxVb+aZOv1rS36bUjcP+bug1W3ZKrTG6
hwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

On server side I need to read the key file and use it for encryption/decryption using PHP. My PHP code is as following:

```c
$pub_key = file_get_contents("../user_pub_key.crt");
$public_key = openssl_pkey_get_public($pub_key);
var_dump($public_key);
echo openssl_error_string();
```

Although $public_key is apparently created and var_dump returns the resource number of it:

```
resource(5) of type (OpenSSL key)
```

but strangely enough, openssl_error_string() is also shows the following error:

```
error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line
```

I spent hours and hours searching for a solution to this. I tried the suggestions about end-of-line characters, encoding, etc., etc. in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20837161/openssl-pem-routinespem-read-biono-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-truste), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630544/cant-get-private-key-with-openssl-no-start-linepem-lib-c703expecting-any-p), [here](https://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/543-how-to-fix-pem-read-bio-no-start-line-error-nginx-error), [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/454926/nginx-ssl-ssl-error0906d06cpem-routinespem-read-biono-start-line), and many more links.

The only suggestions that might be relevant to this problem are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11399613/issues-with-openssl-on-php-different-behaviour-for-different-versions/11427989#11427989) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23462367/encrypt-data-by-using-a-public-key-in-c-sharp-and-decrypt-data-by-using-a-privat), but those solution seem to be for Windows systems not Mac OS, so I couldn't try them.  Your help on this is much appreciated.

p.s. all the development and server are on Mac (not Windows).

Comment: *"but strangely enough, openssl_error_string() is also shows the following error..."* - Maybe your version of PHP is built against OpenSSL 0.9.8 and you are seeing the effects of ABI problems. I believe OS X still ships OpenSSL 0.9.8. Use `otool` to see what libraries PHP is using. Also be sure PHP can find OpenSSL's CONF file.

Comment: @jww, I ran the command `openssl version` and I got `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016`. I'm not familiar with `otool` but the command `otool -L php` listed many libraries including `php:
 /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
 /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)`. And when I run phpinfo in browser I can see `Openssl default config /private/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`. Is there anything needs changing/upgrading on my machine? Thanks in advance for the help.